Grouped Column Header not following sticky while scrolling horizontally
Here's an example:
import { ColDef, ColGroupDef, themeQuartz } from "ag-grid-community";
import { faker } from "@faker-js/faker";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
// import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
// import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css"

const columnDefs: ColGroupDef[] | ColDef[] = [
  { headerName: "Make", field: "make" },
  { headerName: "Model", field: "model" },
  { headerName: "Price", field: "price" },
  {
    headerName: "Value",
    children: Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => ({
      headerName: `Value ${i}`,
      field: `value${i}`,
    })),
  },
];
const data = [
  ...Array.from({ length: 1000 }, (_, i) => ({
    make: faker.vehicle.manufacturer(),
    model: faker.vehicle.model(),
    price: faker.finance.amount(),
    ...Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, j) => ({
      [`value${j}`]: i * 1000 + j,
    })).reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...acc, ...val }), {}),
  })),];

export default function AgGrid() {
  return (
    <div className={"h-[60vh] ag-theme-alpine"}>
      <AgGridReact columnDefs={columnDefs} rowData={data}  theme={themeQuartz}/>
    </div>
  );
}

Unable to do sticky headers:

However, it works if I use CSS styling, like ag-grid.css and ag-theme-alpine.
I can't use CSS overriding because there are many grids in my project and their theme will be different.
Is it a bug or am I missing something?
